# How to connect LED Matrix into Arduino using MAX 7219?

Tags: arduino, led-matrix

I have:

- 2 [8x8 LED Matrix](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=682), and
- a MAX7219 Chip.

**Q:** I just wonder how can I connect that to the **Arduino Duemilanove**?

I have been googling but I couldn't find out how.

Comment: @Bruno - You removed the link, so I thought it was dead. But it's OK, and you didn't explain why you deleted, so I rolled back. If you have a good reason to delete the link, please leave it in the comment field.

Comment: @stevenvh Sorry, I tested it before and it was not working. Maybe I was having some Internet connectivity problems but it's working now. You did well rolling back my edit.

Answer (score 11):

Bryan Chung had a tutorial still available on the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080408123617/http://www.bryanchung.net/?p=177) on how to connect a LED Matrix to an Arduino using a MAX7219:

> Here is an experiment with an 8×8 LED
>   matrix, driven by a MAX7219 IC,
>   controlled through an Arduino
>   micro-controller board. A custom PCB
>   has been made by Tan from DinoTech to
>   tidy up all the wires connecting the
>   LED matrix and the IC. It comes with a
>   separate 12V power supply, in order
>   not to drain everything from the
>   Arduino board.
>
> Only 4 wires are necessary to control
>   the MAX7219 driver IC. They are the
>
> Data Clock Latch/load Ground
>
> The data and clock pins should match
>   those for the shiftOut() command in
>   Arduino. The latch pin will give a LOW
>   to HIGH pulse after the shiftOut
>   command. I have written the original
>   program for Javelin Stamp. Since
>   Arduino can only shift 8 bits of data,
>   I have to use 2 separate commands to
>   shift both the upper and lower bytes
>   to the MAX7219, which needs a 2 bytes
>   control for each command.
>
> For the data structure of the 8×8 LED
>   matrix, I use a byte array – matrix of
>   length 8. Each row in the matrix
>   corresponds to the Y dimension. Each
>   bit in a row corresponds to the X
>   dimension. Digit 1 is on; 0 is off.
>   The X direction is reversed and there
>   is also an 1 bit shift. The
>   updateLED() function caters for this.
>
> The first program is an animation of a
>   single line motion.

```
int CLOCK = 12;
int LATCH = 13;
int DATA  = 11;
byte matrix[8];
int idx = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(CLOCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATA,  OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CLOCK, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DATA,  LOW);
  initLED();
  clearLED();
}

void loop() {
  for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
    updateLED(idx, j, true);
  }
  refreshLED();
  delay(200);
  for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
    updateLED(idx, j, false);
  }
  refreshLED();
  delay(100);
  idx++;
  idx %= 8;
}

void ledOut(int n) {
  digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);
  shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, (n>>8));
  shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, (n));
  digitalWrite(LATCH, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);
}

void initLED() {
  ledOut(0x0B07);
  ledOut(0x0A0C);
  ledOut(0x0900);
  ledOut(0x0C01);
}

void clearLED() {
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    matrix[i] = 0x00;
  }
  refreshLED();
}

void refreshLED() {
  int n1, n2, n3;
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    n1 = i+1;
    n2 = matrix[i];
    n3 = (n1<<8)+n2;
    ledOut(n3);
  }
}

void updateLED(int i, int j, boolean b) {
  int t = 1;
  int n = 0;
  int m = 0;
  if (j==0) {
    m = 7;
  }
  else {
    m = j-1;
  }
  n = t<<m;
  if (b) {
    matrix[i] = n | matrix[i];
  }
  else {
    n = ~n;
    matrix[i] = n & matrix[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if it's a bit late for you, but I've just written a [post about using the MAX7219](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/review-maxim-max7219-led-display-driver-ic/) with LED matrices and 7-segment LED Displays.